# How do you have a template saved with an xml extension be rendered inside a layout in phoenix?

Tags: xml, templates, layout, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a controller producing some xml responses, but if I save my templates with the .xml.eex extension they wont be rendered inside a designated layout. As soon as I save them with the usual .html.eex extension I have no problems. The content is good, and it is sent out as valid xml. I just want my filenames to be more descriptive. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might see, the default phoenix `EEx` engine [comes with `Phoenix.Template.HTML`/`Phoenix.HTML.Engine` only](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/template/eex_engine.ex).

In case of any other file type (read: extension,) it falls back to [`EEx.SmartEngine`](https://hexdocs.pm/eex/EEx.SmartEngine.html#content).

That said there is no room to interfere the `.eex` handling (at the moment.) The good news is Phoenix [supports custom templates engines](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Template.html). You might put

```
config :phoenix, :template_engines,
  exx: MyApp.Template.MyEExEngine
```

and implement the engine yourself (e.g. in your particular case by delegating calls to [`Phoenix.Template.HTML`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Template.HTML.html).) That way you will be able to grant files with `.xml.exx` extensions (or whatever extension you have your engine assigned to.)

Honestly, I won’t do that: too much effort for nothing. Maybe you might submit an issue to `Phoenix` to allow plugging specific engines into default engine (for instance, `Phoenix.Template.EExEngine.engine_for/1` might be looking up the config, or like.)